# div inside button not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Shmoyojoe/KBcwe/16/)

I am making a social button, and I want it to look sort of like a custom g+ sign in button:

[image]

However, when I put the second div (to hold the right part of the button), It doesn't show:

[image]

HTML:

```
<div id='p' style='display: inline-block'>Testing Testing 123</div>
```

CSS:

```
#p {
    height: 25px;
    width: 50px;
    background: #371e41
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no enough space for the letters in the button. If you increase the width of the button, putting for example `width: 300px` in the button, the letters will show.

```
#b {
    height: 25px;
    width: 300px;
    ...
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VSvHE/)

Comment: With that answer, the div `#p` doesn't respond to my CSS formatting. The div is about 15px tall even if I set the height to 100px

Comment: @JJP I don't understand you. I am just giving you the reason why the #p didn't show.